# Terraform Interpolation function "join" errors out on empty value

Tags: terraform

I am trying to use `join` to run multiple `user_data` files where `var.user_data_file` would be common within the module and `var.user_data` would be passed where the module is called. This works without any issues when `var.user_data` is not null, but it does not when it is null

```
  31:   user_data                   = join("\n", [templatefile("../../files/${var.user_data_file}", {
  32:     hostname = "${var.instance_name_tag}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  33:   }), var.user_data])
    |----------------
    |xxxx
    |xxxx
    |xxxx
    | var.user_data is null

Invalid value for "lists" parameter: element 1 is null; cannot concatenate
null values.
```

Am I doing this incorrectly?
Could someone please suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could conditionally join your base user data with the added non null user data variable instead.

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # ...
  user_data = var.user_data != null ? join("\n", [templatefile("../../files/${var.user_data_file}", {
    hostname = "${var.instance_name_tag}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  }), var.user_data]) : templatefile("../../files/${var.user_data_file}", {
    hostname = "${var.instance_name_tag}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  }))
}
```

In this specific case you should also be able to just change your `user_data` variable to default to an empty string instead of using `null`. This would allow you to use the existing `join` that you already had:

```
variable "user_data" {
  default = ""
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # ...
  user_data = join("\n", [templatefile("../../files/${var.user_data_file}", {
    hostname = "${var.instance_name_tag}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  }), var.user_data])
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks a lot. Broken down part with local did not work for me as it needs "count of the instances" and I am not sure how to pass instance count to locals.

Comment: Oh right yeah that would be problematic, I didn't really notice that when scan reading. I'll remove that option. I think your best option is definitely to change the default to an empty string though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Terraform's [compact](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/compact) function, to remove the empty string or null from the join:

```
user_data = join("\n", compact([templatefile("../../files/${var.user_data_file}", {hostname = "${var.instance_name_tag}-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"}), var.user_data]))
```